# UILabel and UIView returns size (0, 0) on viewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

i'm developing an iOS 5 application. I want to resize a UIView programmatically, using its default view. This is view is named cardView.

```
@interface ThreeCardsViewController : UIViewController
{
    ...
    IBOutlet UIView* cardView;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView* cardView;

...
```

When I send a message to a method inside `viewDidAppear`, I get that cardView size is 0x0.

```
@implementation ThreeCardsViewController

...
@synthesize cardView;
...

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self setUpViews];
}

- (void) setUpViews
{
    ...

    futureCardState.cardViewY =
                    [self computeDescriptionViewPosWith:futureCardState.cardViewSize];
    ...

    [self showCard:pastCardState];
}

- (CGFloat) computeDescriptionViewPosWith:(CGSize)newDescriptionViewSize
{
    CGFloat newY;

    newY =  cardView.frame.size.height - newDescriptionViewSize.height;

    return newY;
}
```

All views, or uilabels has size (0, 0).

I'm sure this views are connected with xib, using Interface Builder

Do you know why I'm getting (0, 0)? Where can I do this initialization?

Comment: Show us the code for `setUpView`. Also, make sure you *always* call `super`'s `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: have you synthesis cardView ?

Comment: I've updated my question with new details. @mattjgalloway, I've added [super viewDidAppear:...] and it doesn't work yet.

Comment: what display NSLog(@"%@", cardView); ?

Comment: @HardikShah Oh,sorry. It was my error. I've updated it with the correct format.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've found the answer. I've posted my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

If I use `self.cardView`, **it works!**

```
- (CGFloat) computeDescriptionViewPosWith:(CGSize)newDescriptionViewSize
{
    CGFloat newY;

    newY =  self.cardView.frame.size.height - newDescriptionViewSize.height;

    return newY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check IBOutlets in Xib, and don't forget @synthesize for all your properties.

Comment: All IBOutlets in Xib are correct, and all properties has its @synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

0x0 is not a size it is memory address at which object is allocated. and do in ViewDidAppear before calling method.

```
cardView = [[UIView alloc]init];
```

this will solve the problem

Comment: If cardView hasn't been allocated, I will get an exception. And, sorry, it was my fault. I've used an incorrect format for size.